# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: UI/ChartsFrame

Tags: java, class, classpath

I broke my program its working fine but now can't find class path for one of the classes.I look every where and

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: UI/ChartsFrame

I am using InteliJ last time I broke it can't find class also but I delete some folder and start again.Now I don't remember what was I deleted before.

Comment: Intellij has a local history.  Maybe restore something from rhat?

Comment: I rename  the class  and is working now.